# MSSQL to Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I am trying to import Data from MSSQL into Python - Odoo install. I can import one field with the code below. This works but I want to retrieve other fields besides name.

```
#Retrieve data through recordset
RecCount =rs.RecordCount

print RecCount

while not rs.EOF:
    #  print rs.Fields.item('Description').value
    #  print rs.Fields.item('Price').value
    name = rs.Fields.item('Description').value
    record = {'name' : name}

    filter = [[['name' ,'=', name]]]
    product_id = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'search', filter)

    if not product_id:
        print " Create - " + name
        resultset = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'create', [record])

    else:
        print "Already in table - " + name



    rs.Move(1)
```

I want to to import other fields like the barcode field. below is what I tried but I get an error.

```
#Retrieve data through recordset
RecCount =rs.RecordCount

print RecCount

while not rs.EOF:
    #  print rs.Fields.item('Description').value
    #  print rs.Fields.item('Price').value
    name = rs.Fields.item('Description').value
    barcode = rs.Fields.item('ItemLookupCode').value
    record = {'name' : name}
    recordbarcode = {'barcode' : barcode}

    filter = [[['barcode' ,'=', barcode]]]
    product_id = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'search', filter)

    if not product_id:
        print " Create - " + barcode
        resultset = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'create', ['record']['recordbarcode'] )

    else:
        print "Already in table - " + barcode



    rs.Move(1)
```

The error I get with the above code is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importdataorg.py", line 58, in <module>
    resultset = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'create', ['record']['recordbarcode'] )
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Whatever do you think `['record']['recordbarcode']` does?

Comment: I don't know I was hoping it would insert the barcode field. I am testing/learning

Comment: You have no fields there. That's two strings and two lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure your error is at all related to any tools you're using.

`['record']['recordbarcode']` isn't valid Python.

Just run that alone in the REPL, and `list indices must be integers, not str`

Did you want to use these variables?

```
record = {'name' : name}
recordbarcode = {'barcode' : barcode}
```

If so, `record['name']` is valid, but that is literally just the already available `name` variable.

Maybe you wanted this dictionary

```
{'name' : name, 'barcode' : barcode}
```

Or a list of the two dictionaries

```
[record, recordbarcode]
```

Comment: If I wanted to update a row if a record already exists or create a new one if it doesn't already exist based on the barcode. I tried  resultset = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'update', [record] )

Comment: If you have a new question, please create a new post